# Can Succah schach be used to make sushi that I will eat on Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I noticed that the bamboo mat used to roll sushi is the same shape and material as the huge mats used for the succah.

I know that there is a general rule that items used for *kedushah* - holy purposes should not be used for mundane purposes. Normally, then, I would think that you couldn't use the schach for making sushi.

However, there is a *mitzvah* to eat fish in Shabbat, so, if I reserve the schach for just making sushi for Shabbat, perhaps, this is a "holy" purpose. Would this be permitted?

I am aware that I would be making a giant sushi roll using this large bamboo mat. That's sort of the idea. I have to cater to a hungry family!

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

The kasha is whether doing so will be mevatel the shem schach from it. If you are using it as a kli to make sushi, there is a real fear that by doing so we risk retroactively making this an item with traditional household use so it no longer qualifies as pesoles goren viyekev.

Please keep in mind that, according to chazal, it needs to be at least *possible* for the sun to be seen through the schach, which means that it is certainly already holey. A sufficiently holey schach would be a poor maker of sushi, which means that it would be considered an object only used as a makeshift tool, sidestepping the problem of retroactively making it a kli.

Another serious point of consideration - using a bambo mat to contain your sushi on shabbos might classify as tzeida, as we learn that such mats are used for trapping fish.

So as long as you're really bad at making sushi and aren't serving it to your grandfather, you should be fine.

Unfortunately, this precludes using the schach to operate as a caterer, as one is judged on the quality of their product and we will be choshesh that you will make better sushi than you are supposed to. Also, at a simcha there is no reasonable way for the caterer to divine who is just a party-goer and who is a zeida, so you must refrain from serving your sushi wherever the elderly are present.

Comment: Funny true story about elderly and sushi - My friend's mom saw this raw fish at a wedding shmorg and asked me what it was. When I told her raw fish, she thought I meant "herring". She ate a piece and I thought I was going to have to resuscitate her! She never had something so horrible. I DID warn her it was not herring.